# Extract contents from a line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phrase

I'm trying to phrase my access log file, to do this I simply read the access log file line by line and extract usefull info from each line, finally add them to a database.

For example, a line would look like this.

```
124.99.152.202 - naveen [22/Nov/2013:10:41:17 +1300] "GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078/IneedThisInteger/12.txt HTTP/1.1" "200" "3" "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
```

I only know how to extract IP address.( using [this](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3))

I want to extract

1. this request value-  `GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,IneedThisInteger/12.txt HTTP/1.1`
2. this integer value from above part-  `IneedThisInteger`
3. this status part- `200`
4. this bytes part- `3`

sometimes request URL changes it's **last portion**,

```
"GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,IneedThisInteger/FOLDER/12.txt HTTP/1.1"
"GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,IneedThisInteger/FOLDER/ANOTHER FOLDER/12.txt HTTP/1.1"
"GET /p/V4ZkA5d074CTy_vbFa7nLw,1385070078,IneedThisInteger/FOLDER/ANOTHER FOLDER/HEREIS-ANOTHER-FOLDER-AND-SO-ON/12.txt HTTP/1.1"
```

So I really need a stable way to get those values from each line.How do I do this?

Comment: Well you answered your question by choosing the appropriate tag: using regex

Comment: @kingkero The question is how to do this using regex, I tried using a online tool as I mentioned above but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+).*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://www.rexfiddle.net/3sDwWut

I replaced your "I NEED THIS INTEGER" with an actual number for testing purposes, and also randomized the "bytes" and IP addresses a little bit. These are the captures, in order:

1. The IP
2. The request (e.g. `GET xxx HTTP/1.1`)
3. The integer from the URL you wanted
4. The HTTP status
5. The byte count

Comment: this is great but I've no idea how you did this. thanks SpikeX

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are always having GET requests, this should do the trick

```
"(GET /.*?/.*?,\d+,(\d+)/.*?)"\s"(\d+)"\s"(\d+)"
```

See [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/uE7pJ8) for explanation of the expression.